# Selling public domain ebook, how to avoid copyright infringement in the US?

Tags: united-states, copyright

I made an ebook from a 1936 publication (country of origin: UK) and preparing to sell it on my website with the help of a credit card processor. The book is under copyright in the United States but public domain almost everywhere else. I am not a US citizen, not located in the US, and not doing business through a US legal entity.

1. Is there a standard course of action in this situation to avoid copyright infringement?
2. What determines copyright infringement here, the buyer's US citizenship or the buyer's country of residence?
3. Am I responsible for verifying the buyer's US citizenship/residence and if so, what are the minimal requirements? Would it be enough to simply ask the buyer to select from a dropdown of whitelisted countries before placing the order?

Comment: Relevant: https://m.wikihow.com/Sell-Public-Domain-eBooks

Answer (score 2):

### You can’t

Assuming the book is still under copyright in the USA (which is by no means certain) and the USA is the “country of origin” under the [Berne Convention](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) then it is still under copyright in most signatory countries.

Comment: I forgot to specify in the question that it was published in the UK, not the US. I edited the question.

Comment: P.S. I am also not certain that the book is under copyright in the US, but I have some reasons to believe that it is, so for now I am operating on that assumption. See my question here if you have interest in this issue: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24882/book-published-in-the-uk-public-domain-in-home-country-still-under-us-copyrigh

Comment: If it was published in the UK *first* then unless the author died before 1958 its still under copyright everywhere. If they did die before 1958 it’s under copyright nowhere.